# How to use saxon on Tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat, xslt, saxon

We are building applications using XSLT under CentOS 7.6, tomcat 9.0.20, and OpenJDK11.

I want to convert and output an XML document defined in a JSP file with XSL, but the following error message is output,
I can not use the saxon extension.

[Error message]
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Unknown extension instruction saxon: while

You can use the saxon extension in CentOS 6.x, tomcat 8.0.9, and Oracle JDK 1.8.112 environments.

If you know how to solve the error, please tell us what information you need.

Below are the steps taken to check the operation after setting up the environment, and the error message details.

1. Create JSP file and XSL file and place them under Tomcat examples.

[SaxonSample.jsp : /opt/tomcat/webapps/examples/jsp/xml/SaxonSample.jsp]

```
    <%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix = "x" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>

    <html>
       <head>
          <title>JSTL x:transform Tags</title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <h3>Books Info:</h3>
          <c:set var = "xmltext">
             <books>
                <book>
                   <name>Padam History</name>
                   <author>ZARA</author>
                   <price>100</price>
                </book>

                <book>
                   <name>Great Mistry</name>
                   <author>NUHA</author>
                   <price>2000</price>
                </book>
             </books>
          </c:set>
          <c:import url = "http://server_ip:8080/examples/jsp/xml/style.xsl" var = "xslt"/>
          <x:transform xml = "${xmltext}" xslt = "${xslt}"/>
       </body>
    </html>
```

[style.xsl : /opt/tomcat/webapps/examples/jsp/xml/style.xsl]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
            extension-element-prefixes="saxon"
    >

    <xsl:variable name="i" select="0" saxon:assignable="yes"/>
    <xsl:output method = "html" indent = "yes"/>
       <xsl:template match = "/">
          <html>
             <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
             </body>
          </html>
          <saxon:while test="$i &lt; 10">
              <p>The value of i is <xsl:value-of select="$i"/></p>
              <saxon:assign name="i" select="$i+1"/>
          </saxon:while>
       </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match = "books">
          <table border = "1" width = "100%">
             <xsl:for-each select = "book">
                <tr>
                   <td>
                      <i><xsl:value-of select = "name"/></i>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select = "author"/>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select = "price"/>
                   </td>
                </tr>
             </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
       </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

2. Place the saxon library below and restart tomcat

   ・ Saxon9pe.jar
   ・ Saxon9pe-test.jar
   ・ Saxon9-sql.jar
   ・ Saxon-license.lic

Location: [/opt/tomcat/lib] and [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/lib/]

[Error message details]

```
    net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Unknown extension instruction saxon:while
        net.sf.saxon.expr.ErrorExpression.evaluateItem(ErrorExpression.java:137)
        net.sf.saxon.expr.Expression.process(Expression.java:929)
        net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:689)
        net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.TemplateRule.applyLeavingTail(TemplateRule.java:347)
        net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:505)
        net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:2411)
        net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1979)
        net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer.transform(XsltTransformer.java:596)
        net.sf.saxon.jaxp.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:73)
        org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.TransformSupport.doEndTag(TransformSupport.java:151)
        org.apache.jsp.jsp.xml.SaxonSample_jsp._jspx_meth_x_005ftransform_005f0(SaxonSample_jsp.java:281)
        org.apache.jsp.jsp.xml.SaxonSample_jsp._jspService(SaxonSample_jsp.java:154)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Comment: It might be that the license file is not found.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
When running on Tomcat, do you recognize that placing license file and jar in the same directory is not enough?

Comment: Are file names on your OS case-sensitive? I think the expected name is all lower-case `saxon-license.lic` while your text says you have `Saxon-license.lic`.

Comment: I have no knowledge of Tomcat setup but Saxon's doc state "In Tomcat, for example, the license file should be treated in the same way as free-standing (unjarred) classes, and placed in the WEB-INF/classes directory": http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/about/license/licensekey.html

Comment: I'm sorry. There was an error in the description.
The license file is in lowercase letters.
 saxon-license.lic

Since the evaluation license has just expired, we will reapply and try again.
As soon as the license arrives, try checking the file name and placing it in the classes directory.

Answer (score 0):

This does look like a configuration problem picking up the license file.

The mechanism of simply putting the license file in the same folder as the JAR file works in some environments but not others; it depends on what class loader is used to load the Saxon classes (some class loaders don't allow Saxon to discover the location that it was loaded from for security reasons).

I see that you're invoking Saxon via JAXP interfaces.

If you set the feature "http://saxon.sf.net/feature/timing" to true on the TransformerFactory then there will be messages logged to System.err showing the progress of the search for a license file, which may be helpful for diagnostics.  If you can't work out where Tomcat is putting the System.err output, then you can redirect it by casting the `TransformerFactory` to a `TransformerFactoryImpl` and calling `getConfiguration().setStandardErrorOutput(printStream)`.

Alternatively you can try setting the property `"http://saxon.sf.net/feature/licenseFileLocation"` on the `TransformerFactory` to the full path of the license file.

Comment: Thank you for your specific answer.

An evaluation license file will be available tomorrow.
Immediately after obtaining the license file, we will verify the method taught.